# leaflet polyline eventlistener find the position of click

Tags: angular, events, leaflet, maps, polyline

I use Leaflet for a map. I created a polyline

```
var polylinePoints = [
[37.781814, -122.404740],
[37.781719, -122.404637],
[37.781489, -122.404949],
[37.780704, -122.403945],
[37.780012, -122.404827]];             
 var polyline = L.polyline(polylinePoints).addTo(map);
```

furthermore I added the on()

```
polyline.on("click", function (e) {
etc etc etc
})
```

I want when I click on polyline, to find the place of click event. In which one point of polylinePoints is between.

How can I use the event please?

thank you